# Why doesn't this recursive search go to the 2nd level?

Tags: c, search, recursion, directory

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

void ini(char*, char*);
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{

  if(args!=3) {printf("Enter correct format: myls.out . an"); return 0;}
  ini(argv[1],argv[2]);

  return 0;
}
void ini(char* dir,char* match)
{
  DIR* dirp;
  dirp = opendir(dir);
  if ( dirp == NULL )
  {
    printf("\ndir open error\n");
    exit(1);
  } //Error for opening dir
  else
  {
    struct stat fst;
    struct dirent* dentry;
    dentry = readdir(dirp);

    while ( dentry != NULL )
    {
      if ( !stat(dentry->d_name, &fst) )
      {
        // report as whether is a directory or regular file
        if ( S_ISDIR(fst.st_mode) )
        {
            if( !strcmp(dentry->d_name,".") || !strcmp(dentry->d_name,"..") );

            else
            {
                char fullpath[1024];

                strcpy(fullpath,dir);
                strcat(fullpath,"/");
                strcat(fullpath,dentry->d_name);

                ini(fullpath,match);
            }

        }
        else if ( S_ISREG(fst.st_mode) )
        {
             if(strstr(dentry->d_name,match)!=NULL)
                printf("%s/%s \n",dir,dentry->d_name);
        }

      }

      dentry = readdir(dirp);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

This program takes 2 arguments. Sample run:

```
 ./a.out . an
./andy.txt
./subdir/band.out
./subdir/cs337/handy.c
./than.text
```

When the argument name is a substring of a file's name, display full path and the name of the file. The problem of my code is that it only goes one level down. Can anyone help me?
Sample:

```
./a.out . an
./andy.txt
./subdir/band.out
./than.text
```

Comment: The problem is `stat(dentry->d_name, &fst)` is just passed a file name without the full path name. So if it's not in the current directory, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `fullpath` to `stat`, otherwise it's not going to tell you that you are looking at a directory:

```
while ( dentry != NULL ) {
    // Make full path right away
    char fullpath[1024];
    strcpy(fullpath,dir);
    strcat(fullpath,"/");
    strcat(fullpath,dentry->d_name);
    if ( !stat(fullpath, &fst) ) { // Pass fullpath to stat
        // report as whether is a directory or regular file
        if ( S_ISDIR(fst.st_mode) ) {
            if( !strcmp(dentry->d_name,".") || !strcmp(dentry->d_name,"..") )
                ;
            ini(fullpath,match);
        } else if ( S_ISREG(fst.st_mode) && strstr(dentry->d_name,match)!=NULL) {
            // Combine two conditions to eliminate "if"
            printf("%s/%s \n",dir,dentry->d_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After using "continue" statement, my program doesn't output anything.

Comment: @Robin You're right, I should have tried this change before suggesting it. The problem is that with the `continue` the loop never reaches `dentry = readdir(dirp);`, so it continues iterating in a busy loop. I fixed the answer to go back to your version of the code.